# Is it possible to develop for the browser, android, and iphone with the core logic written in C++?

Tags: android, c++, ios, applet, java-web-start

With some Googling it appears this is possible in iOS, Android using the NDK, and in a browser using Java Web Start or a Java Applet.  I understand the GUI for iOS and Android will have to be done using Objective-C and Java.  If this is even possible how practical is it when you start to consider debugging support?

Answer (score 2):

The Objective-C runtime can be accessed through a [C api](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html), so it is possible to write code for iOS and Cocoa using pure C++.

For web development, there is nothing that I know of that is currently available that allows you to deploy code written in C++. This is because C++ is usually compiled into native code, which is very difficult to sandbox and which would imply a security hole. In the future, it may be possible to run such code with [Native Client](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/). At the moment it is still in development, but it is already partially functional as an experimental extension to Chromium.

For Android, your code must always run in the Dalvik JVM, but you can incorporate C++ that has been compiled into native code by using the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for the browser, but I've been doing C++ on iOS for almost a couple years now. Both [Fieldrunners](http://fieldrunners.com/) and [Autodesk Tinkerbox](http://tinkerboxnews.com/) (both of which I work on) are C++. The GUI is also custom C++. There is only a tiny amount of Objective-C so that the C++ code can interface with iOS. The Android version of Fieldrunners also uses the C++ codebase with just a tiny amount of Java, again as glue code.